# Sign in with google. Get profile details using Asynchronous task

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, async-await, google-signin

I am using this code to login with google. And trying to get user details.

```
else if (Session["loginTo"].ToString() == "google")
                { 

                    var url = Request.Url.Query;
                    if (url != "")
                    {
                        string queryString = url.ToString();
                        char[] delimiterChars = { '=' };
                        string[] words = queryString.Split(delimiterChars);
                        string codeg = words[1];

                        if (codeg != null)
                        {


                            //get the access token 
                            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
                            webRequest.Method = "POST";
                            Parameters = "code=" + codeg + "&client_id=" + ggl_app_key + "&client_secret=" + ggl_app_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + ggl_redirect_url + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
                            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parameters);
                            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                            Stream postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                            // Add the post data to the web request
                            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                            postStream.Close();

                            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
                            postStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postStream);
                            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                            GooglePlusAccessToken serStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlusAccessToken>(responseFromServer);

                            if (serStatus != null)
                            {
                                string accessToken = string.Empty;
                                accessToken = serStatus.access_token;
                                //getgoogleplususerdataSer(accessToken);

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                                {
                                    // This is where you want to add the code if login is successful.
                                     getgoogleplususerdataSer(accessToken);
                                }


                            }


                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }


    public class GooglePlusAccessToken
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
        public string id_token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }

    private async void getgoogleplususerdataSer(string access_token)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + access_token;

            client.CancelPendingRequests();
            HttpResponseMessage output = await client.GetAsync(urlProfile);

            if (output.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string outputData = await output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                GoogleUserOutputData serStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleUserOutputData>(outputData);

                if (serStatus != null)
                {
                    // You will get the user information here.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catching the exception
        }

    }



    public class GoogleUserOutputData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string given_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

I have written this code on my master page. But getting error at method call 'getgoogleplususerdataSer(accessToken);' error is  "An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>"